# Is it possible to programmatically set the user account for a windows service?

Tags: c#, windows, vb.net, windows-services

I have created a windows service that has the Account set to user.  Which means that when I install the service I need to pass a user name and password.  Is there a way to set these maybe in the ProjectInstaller class maybe in the BeforeInstall event?  if so HOW?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceprocessinstaller.username.aspx)

Comment: Can you use this to set the username & password at runtime (rather than compile-time)? Wouldn't you need to be able to get to the installers that are already compiled into your service executable? I'll probably have to go the WMI route instead.

Comment: Your service can have its own installer class that inherits from "System.Configuration.Install.Installer".  We use this inherited class and associate a form with it.  The form comes up during the install and prompts for various things, including user/password.  Then in the Installer class you override OnBeforeInstall and set Me.ServiceProcessInstaller1.Username.

Comment: And modify windows service account for WinService that yet exists?

Answer (score 6):

The below addition to a project installer will assign the service Log On information during installation.

```
    public ProjectInstaller()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.<account type>;
        serviceProcessInstaller1.Username = <domain\userId>;
        serviceProcessInstaller1.Password = <password>;
    }
```

Comment: If you do not specify an Account in code and have the ServiceProcessInstaller Property for Account set to User a form dialog will open during the installation that will allow the individual who performs the installation to specify a domain user account and password.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [DynamicInstaller from CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/DynWinServiceInstallUtil.aspx?msg=2292835)

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit about setting service parameters and stuff in [A Windows Service without a template](http://www.i-programmer.info/projects/38-windows/276-a-windows-service-without-a-template.html) Its on page 5 in the bit about customising a service.